# How to make curly braces collapsable in BBEdit (TextWrangler) for ruby on rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bbedit

So I really like how BBEdit allows you to fold blocks of code. But for Ruby code it doesn't recognize curly braces as a place to insert folds automatically. Is it possible to tweak the preferences in a way that lets me to collapse/expand code between curly braces (JavaScript code is like that)?

Hope this makes sense to someone.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby selected in the language popup I do get that functionality. Perhaps you don't have Ruby selected in the language popup?

(I also didn't try this with the "Ruby in HTML" language setting - maybe you're using that?)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I just tried the same snippet that you have shown and it did work. Originally I wanted to fold code with braces that looks like this: `@tasks = Task.to_json(:include => {...some nested code here...})` Do you think that it is possible?